# Constrained Value Types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, immutability, value-type

Is it possible to define constrained types in Haskell, i.e. I would like to be able to express,

```
Prelude> let legalCharacters = ' ':['A'..'Z']
Prelude> legalCharacters
" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

as a type, if possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can be done in modern GHC (>= 7.10, perhaps already 7.8).

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, DataKinds, MonoLocalBinds #-}
import GHC.TypeLits

newtype LegalChar (legalSet :: Symbol)
   = LegalChar {getLegalChar :: Char}
  deriving (Show)

fromChar :: KnownSymbol legal => Char -> Maybe (LegalChar legal)
fromChar c
   | c`elem`symbolVal r = Just r
   | otherwise          = Nothing
 where r = LegalChar c
```

Then

```
*Main> fromChar 'a' :: Maybe (LegalChar "abc")
Just (LegalChar {getLegalChar = 'a'})
*Main> fromChar 'x' :: Maybe (LegalChar "abc")
Nothing
```

I think in GHC-8 you can even give `legalSet` the kind `String` and do away with the `KnownSymbol` constraint, not sure how that would work.

Comment: I got the following error with GHC 8.0.1: `Could not deduce (KnownSymbol n0) arising from a use of ‘symbolVal’ [...] The type variable ‘n0’ is ambiguous`. Making `legal` a scoped type variable and giving a signature for `r` solved the issue. I'm confused though why it couldn't infer the type of `r`.

Comment: @jpath it can actually infer this, but only when `-XMonoLocalBinds` is enabled. I didn't notice, because I have `-XGADTs` in my `.ghci` file, which implies `-XMonoLocalBinds`.